# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types exception in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using MySql database, if I execute the solution I am getting the exception in catch block, below is my code

```
MySqlManager dac = new MySqlManager();
long value = 0;
DbCommand dbCommand = dac.GetStoredProcCommand("Spforgotpassword");
dac.AddOutParameter(dbCommand, "p_op_EmailId", DbType.Int32, -1);
dac.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_p_EmailId", DbType.String, data.Email_Id);
dac.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_p_Password", DbType.String, Generatehash256(data.Password));
dac.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_P_EncryptedPassword", DbType.String, Encryption.Encrypt(data.Password));
dac.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_P_Mode", DbType.String, 102);
dac.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "p_IPAddress", DbType.String, data.IPAddress);
IDataReader reader = dac.ExecuteReader(dbCommand);
if (reader.Read())
{
    value = reader["result"] == DBNull.Value ? default(long) : Convert.ToInt32(reader["result"]);
}
dac.CloseConnection(dbCommand, reader);
if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["EnableEmail"]))
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(dac.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "p_op_EmailId")) != -1)
    {
        Mail.WebMail oWebmail = new Mail.WebMail(dac.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "p_op_EmailId").ToString());

    }
}
return value;
```

Once I execute this line I am getting the exception as --- *Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types*

```
dac.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "p_op_EmailId")
```

the **p_op_EmailId** is the output parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the stored procedure sets the value of `p_op_EmailId` to `null`. So you cannot convert it to `Int32` directly.

Instead you can cast it to a nullable int, and coalesce it to `-1` before comparing:

```
(dac.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "p_op_EmailId") as int? ?? -1) != -1
```

Comment: Im facing the same issue for this also, can you help me please `data.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dac.GetParameterValue(dbCommand, "p_op_Id"));`

Comment: You can use the same pattern. Instead of using `Convert.ToInt32` use `... as int? ?? -1`.